# How to use Python to measure speed of bike like a digital speedometer, using a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am working on a project using a Raspberry Pi and done code in Python. My project is to measure the distance from all side of bike and speed of bike. I am able to measure distance using an ultrasonic sensor, but trying to measure speed using hall effect sensor but I am getting abnormal speed readings.

For instance, I get 10km/h for another instance it give 99km/h and so on. I want reading like original speedometer which gives gradual incremental or decremental readings.And one more thing I am using multiple functions in the same file and working on multiple GPIO pins is that make my program slow.

How to improve the speed so I would not miss any pulse from any GPIO? Here is my code and output file.

Code for distance measurement

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
import csv
from time import sleep
import math
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

TRIG1=7    #front ultrasonic sensor configuration
ECHO1=12

TRIG2=11  #back ultrasonic sensor configuration
ECHO2=15

TRIG3=13  #left ultrasonic sensor configuration
ECHO3=16

TRIG4=18    #right ultrasonic sensor configuration
ECHO4=22

j=10000    # maximum number of readings
data=[]


GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(TRIG1,0)        #front us sensor setup
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.IN)
time.sleep(0.0001)

GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(TRIG2,0)   #back us sensor setup
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.IN)
time.sleep(0.0001)

GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(TRIG1,0)   #left us sensor setup
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.IN)
time.sleep(0.0001)

GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(TRIG2,0)  #right us sensor setup
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.IN)
time.sleep(0.0001)

print ("starting measurements...........")

def front():
      GPIO.output(TRIG1,1)
      time.sleep(0.0001)#distance from front sensor
      GPIO.output(TRIG1,0)
      start1=time.time()
      stop1=time.time()
      while GPIO.input(ECHO1) == 0:
            start1=time.time()
      while GPIO.input(ECHO1) == 1:
            stop1=time.time()
      time1=stop1-start1
      distance1=time1 * 17000
      return distance1

def back():
      GPIO.output(TRIG2,1)
      time.sleep(0.0001) 
      GPIO.output(TRIG2,0)    #distance from back sensor
      start2=time.time()
      stop2=time.time()
      while GPIO.input(ECHO2) == 0:
            start2=time.time()
      while GPIO.input(ECHO2) == 1:
            stop2=time.time()
      time2=stop2-start2
      distance2=time2 * 17000
      return distance2
def left():
      GPIO.output(TRIG3,1)
      time.sleep(0.0001)
      GPIO.output(TRIG3,0)#distance from left sensor
      start3=time.time()
      stop3=time.time()
      while GPIO.input(ECHO3) == 0:
            start3=time.time()
      while GPIO.input(ECHO3) == 1:
            stop3=time.time()
      time3=stop3-start3
      distance3=time3 * 17000
      return distance3

def right():
      GPIO.output(TRIG4,1)
      time.sleep(0.0001)
      GPIO.output(TRIG4,0)  #distance from right sensor
      start4=time.time()
      stop4=time.time()
      while GPIO.input(ECHO4) == 0:
            start4=time.time()
      while GPIO.input(ECHO4) == 1:
            stop4=time.time()
      time4=stop4-start4
      distance4=time4 * 17000
      return distance4

with open('test.csv','w') as testfile:
      csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
      while j:
            distance1=front()
            distance2=back()
            distance3=left()
            distance4=right()
            data.append([distance1,distance2,distance3,distance4,time.ctime()])
            csv_writer.writerow([distance1,distance2,distance3,distance4,time.ctime()])
            time.sleep(0.5)
            j=j-1

lenth=len(data)
print (data) 
GPIO.cleanup ()
```

and for speed measurement:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import time, math

dist_meas = 0.00
km_per_hour = 0
rpm = 0
elapse = 0
sensor = 29
pulse = 0
start_timer = time.time()

def init_GPIO():               # initialize GPIO
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
   GPIO.setwarnings(False)
   GPIO.setup(sensor,GPIO.IN,GPIO.PUD_UP)

def calculate_elapse(channel):            # callback function
   global pulse, start_timer, elapse
   pulse+=1                        # increase pulse by 1 whenever interrupt occurred
   elapse = time.time() - start_timer      # elapse for every 1 complete rotation made!
   start_timer = time.time()            # let current time equals to start_timer

def calculate_speed(r_cm):
   global pulse,elapse,rpm,dist_km,dist_meas,km_per_sec,km_per_hour
   if elapse !=0:                     # to avoid DivisionByZero error
      rpm = 1/elapse * 60
      circ_cm = (2*math.pi)*r_cm         # calculate wheel circumference in CM
      dist_km = circ_cm/100000          # convert cm to km
      km_per_sec = dist_km / elapse      # calculate KM/sec
      km_per_hour = km_per_sec * 3600      # calculate KM/h
      dist_meas = (dist_km*pulse)*1000   # measure distance traverse in meter
      return km_per_hour

def init_interrupt():
   GPIO.add_event_detect(sensor, GPIO.FALLING, callback = calculate_elapse, bouncetime = 20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   init_GPIO()
   init_interrupt()
   while True:
      calculate_speed(24)   # call this function with wheel radius as parameter
      print('rpm:{0:.0f}-RPM kmh:{1:.0f}-KMH dist_meas:{2:.2f}m pulse:{3}'.format(rpm,km_per_hour,dist_meas,pulse))
      sleep(0.1)
```

I am getting output for speed like this

```
rpm:0-RPM kmh:0-KMH dist_meas:0.00m pulse:0

rpm:4-RPM kmh:0-KMH dist_meas:1.51m pulse:1

rpm:4-RPM kmh:0-KMH dist_meas:1.51m pulse:1

rpm:4-RPM kmh:0-KMH dist_meas:1.51m pulse:1

rpm:4-RPM kmh:0-KMH dist_meas:1.51m pulse:1

rpm:4-RPM kmh:0-KMH dist_meas:1.51m pulse:1

rpm:104-RPM kmh:9-KMH dist_meas:3.02m pulse:2

rpm:433-RPM kmh:39-KMH dist_meas:4.52m pulse:3

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:365-RPM kmh:33-KMH dist_meas:6.03m pulse:4

rpm:22-RPM kmh:2-KMH dist_meas:7.54m pulse:5

rpm:22-RPM kmh:2-KMH dist_meas:7.54m pulse:5

rpm:229-RPM kmh:21-KMH dist_meas:9.05m pulse:6

rpm:388-RPM kmh:35-KMH dist_meas:10.56m pulse:7

rpm:388-RPM kmh:35-KMH dist_meas:10.56m pulse:7

rpm:971-RPM kmh:88-KMH dist_meas:13.57m pulse:9

rpm:627-RPM kmh:57-KMH dist_meas:15.08m pulse:10

rpm:318-RPM kmh:29-KMH dist_meas:16.59m pulse:11

rpm:1949-RPM kmh:176-KMH dist_meas:19.60m pulse:13

rpm:656-RPM kmh:59-KMH dist_meas:21.11m pulse:14
```

Comment: Could the fluctuations be a result of not ironing out your readings by taking a mean? I should think inaccuracies that come from measuring speed over very short distances would need a great deal of averaging out.

Comment: RPM readings increase as well as decrease but does not show 0.for example if I started measuring, readings start from 0 , increases as speed increase and also decreases to certain level and if we stop wheel then it will continue to show last reading for example if last reading was 2rpm then it will continue showing 2 rpm instead of showing 0.

Comment: Is that because you are no longer receiving pulses from the Hall Effect sensor? That would be expected, I think. If I stop my electric bike quickly, then the display starts to wind down the current speed (probably linearly) and it takes a couple of seconds to reduce to zero. You will probably have to do that yourself.

Comment: yes, i understand that I am if pulses start to reduce the readings reduce but when I stop rotating the wheel,then I am not getting any pulses from the sensor so my counter should automatically reset to 0 instead of keep showing last value.I just Need help in changing the code to achieve this.And thank you for help

Comment: Well, if it is anything like the magnet/sensor configuration on most electric bikes, then no: you only will get a pulse (on/off) when the magnet passes over the sensor. So if you stop, or ride very slowly, then the last pulse becomes so long ago then your speed calculation is essentially out of date, and you need to **manually** taper the speed down to zero. If you believe that your "counter should automatically reset to 0" then can you identify which piece of code shown above does that?

Comment: Oh, I see: "I just need help in changing the code to achieve this" - OK, well that is probably too broad for here. It is generally better for you to try writing that code and then asking for help if it produces incorrect results. Personally I would start off with a design or pseudocode algorithm. I think I would set up an event system called at regular intervals (e.g. 10 times a second) to consider the last few pulses received and the times they were received.

Comment: You could then write a tapering down func so that the age of newest items in the buffer past 3 seconds reduces the speed display by  15%, until it just displays zero. Of course, write a system to test it without the hardware - the tests should run in Python on their own. You'll find it much easier to write that way.

Comment: thank you,  sir, for your help but I am a beginner in programming and I am from a mechanical engineering.I would love to do it myself but I tried so many methods to reset my counter I fail each time.so I am requesting you that if possible can you provide me an example code to achieve this.

Comment: I doubt that would be possible for anyone without the hardware you are testing against. Perhaps someone with the same hardware will see this.

Comment: ok thanks for your help I will try to solve it by myself

Comment: Actually, it should be possible to solve it without your hardware - the pulses can be emulated in software. Perhaps a good way to tackle it is to design the algorithm first, so it does the tapering down when pulses are not received. Start there.

Answer (score 0):

i do found code that give fast results. maybe its help you... anyway im using hall effect magnetic sensors

```
$

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

pulse = 0
distance = 0
rpm = 0.00
speed = 0.00
wheel_c = 20
hall = 18
elapse = 0.00

start = time.time()

GPIO.setup(hall, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)


def get_rpm():
    return rpm

def get_speed():
    return speed

def get_distance():
    return distance

def get_elapse():
    return elapse

def get_pulse(number):
    global elapse,distance,start,pulse,speed,rpm,multiplier
    cycle = 0
    pulse+=1
    cycle+=1
    if pulse > 0:
        elapse = time.time() - start
        pulse -=1
    if cycle > 0:
        distance += wheel_c
        cycle -= 1

    speed = (wheel_c*multiplier)/100000
    rpm = 1/elapse *60

    start = time.time()



try:

    time.sleep(1)

    GPIO.add_event_detect(hall,GPIO.FALLING,callback = get_pulse,bouncetime=20)
    while True:
    print('rpm:{0:.2f} speed:{1:.2f} distance:{2} elapse:{3:.4f}'.format(rpm,speed,distance,elapse))
        time.sleep(0.1) #to reduce CPU load, print every 100 milliseconds


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('You have pressed Ctrl+C! How dare you stopped this beautiful thing?!')
    GPIO.cleanup()
$
```